# Como criar modelos no iReport?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, ireport, relatório

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de usar um modelo criado por mim em outros relatórios? Quero que todos os relatórios do meu sistema sigam um padrão, mas como fazer isso?

Comment: Comece um relatório em Branco e vá "modelando" ele

Comment: Quero saber como repetir este modelo em outros

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode criar templates customizadas dessa forma basta você escolher a template padrão do seu sistema quando clicar em Novo, para criar um novo relatório.

Para você criar uma nova template crie um relatório modelo salve o .jrxml em uma pasta de sua preferência e depois vá em Ferramentas >>> Opções >>> IReport >>>  Templates e indique o caminho dessa pasta.

Quando você clicar em Arquivo >>> Novo, após reiniciar o IReport, vai aparecer seu modelo.

Caso não consiga tem um tutorial neste link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-custom-template